# Nullable DateTime and the Database

Tags: c#, visual-web-developer

I've got a nullable datetime object in C#.

```
DateTime? StartDate = new DateTime();
```

I then check a user submitted value to determine if a date is applicable to this record:

```
if (Complete == "N/A")
{
    StartDate = null;
}
```

Now I come to my query which may or may not be inserting a null datetime:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateSql, db))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Date_Started", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = StartDate;
}
```

As you'd probably expect if the start date is null then I get an error that the type is not correct. What's the best way to proceed from here?

I have considered checking startdate is null but am not sure how to do that when the type is nullable.

Comment: As an aside, you can easily check if a nullable type is null in two ways. 1) `!StartDate.HasValue`, or 2) Simply `StartDate == null`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will pass a database NULL value as the parameter if StartDate is null:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateSql, db))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@Date_Started", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = (object)StartDate ?? DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was attempting, didn't know of this shorthand syntax though! :)

Comment: Error with this too: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type system.datetime? and system.dbnull.

Comment: @deed02392 fixed with a simple cast to object

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateSql, db))
{
    if (StartDate.HasValue())
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date_Started", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value
            = StartDate;
    else
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date_Started", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value 
            = DBNull.Value;
}
```